# Equivalent of Material.alpha and Material.use_transparency

Tags: python, scripting, materials, export, add-on

I am working on upgrading a 2.79 plugin to 2.8.

The plugin was using the `Material.use_transparency` and `Material.alpha` fields, which got both removed in the 2.8 api change.

I am new to this, and I wonder what is the new equivalent of these fields, or if there is a new way to get these information.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complex because materials now almost always use nodes.

Whether to use alpha is controlled by the [Blend Method](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#blend-mode). As a replacement for reading `material.use_transparency`, try using `material.blend_method != 'OPAQUE'`.

To fetch the actual alpha value is harder since it now flows down an arbitrarily-complex node graph. But for simple graphs you can try this

```py
from bpy_extras.node_shader_utils import PrincipledBSDFWrapper
ma_wrap = PrincipledBSDFWrapper(material)
ma_wrap.alpha  # use this instead of material.alpha
ma_wrap.alpha_texture.image  # use this if you want the alpha texture image
```

This wrapper is used by the OBJ/FBX exporter. See [Import & Export of Node Shaders](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html) in the manual for more about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll study the method used by the official exporters then.